# What are best practices when creating an anonymous variable with static lifetime?

Tags: rust, static, macros, higher-order-functions

This a two-part question: (1) Is it good practice to pass higher-order functions static references in order for them (the parameters) to live long enough? (2) What is the best way to create an anonymous variable with static lifetime?

Here's the context: I have a meta-function that returns a closure based on its parameters. In order to make sure the parameters live long enough, they must be static references. E.g.,

```
pub enum Uncloneable { Variant }

pub fn get_getter(param:&'static Uncloneable)
                  -> Box<dyn Fn() -> &'static Uncloneable> {
    Box::new(move || { param })
}
```

But I don't want to clutter my code with lots of `const` definitions every time I call `get_getter`, e.g.

```
fn main() {
    let _result = get_getter({
        const VAR:Uncloneable = Uncloneable::Variant;
        &VAR
    });
}
```

My current solution is to use a macro:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! staticify {
    ($type:tt :: $variant:tt) => {{
        const VAR:$type = $type::$variant;
        &VAR
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let _result = get_getter(staticify!(Uncloneable::Variant));
}
```

which works great, but I'm worried I may be reinventing the wheel here (or even committing some anti-pattern).

[Here's he full code on Rust Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=347615501d39a0a0629a1a5adc7bf70f)

Comment: Do you realize you don't need all of that or is your real use-case more complicated? `get_getter(&Uncloneable::Variant)` just works for this example.

Comment: It turns out I was misinterpreting a compiler error, which made me think all of this was necessary. Thank you for kindly pointing out a very silly mistake!

Comment: On a side note, per the [C-GETTER](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#c-getter) API guideline, a more conventional name for the function `get_getter` would be just `getter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your macro is an antipattern, but it's not necessarily very useful in this case. `const` doesn't allocate any storage for the value, it just does substitution at compile time, so your code is the same as just:

```rust
fn main() {
    let _result = get_getter(&Uncloneable::Variant);
}
```

In other words, it not necessary nor different to use a `const` to store the value.

In addition, the reference is automatically promoted to a `&'static Uncloneable`. The [Rust reference explains](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes):

> When using a value expression in most place expression contexts, a temporary unnamed memory location is created initialized to that value and the expression evaluates to that location instead, except if promoted to `'static`. **Promotion of a value expression to a `'static` slot occurs when the expression could be written in a constant, borrowed, and dereferencing that borrow where the expression was originally written, without changing the runtime behavior.** That is, the promoted expression can be evaluated at compile-time and the resulting value does not contain interior mutability or destructors (these properties are determined based on the value where possible, e.g. `&None` always has the type `&'static Option<_>`, as it contains nothing disallowed).

So essentially, if you can use a constant like your code, you can also just take a reference of that value directly, and it will be promoted to a `'static` reference automatically if it can be.

Comment: It turns out I was misinterpreting a compiler error, which made me think all of this was necessary. Thank you for kindly pointing out a very silly mistake and for all the context!